# Error: Attempt to Use Closed ZIP Archive When Extracting Files

Tags: python, zip, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

Despite the code having worked previously, it is now encountering this error. The provided code includes an attempt to create a directory and open a ZIP file for extraction, but it closes the ZIP archive, leading to the error. The goal is to find a solution to keep the ZIP archive open for multiple operations.

```
    ValueError: Attempt to use ZIP archive that was already closed
```

here is my code

```
hyper = os.path.join(current_directory, r'Hyper_Output')
if not os.path.exists(hyper):
    os.makedirs(hyper)
```

```
with zipfile.ZipFile(f""+hyper+"/Rules.tdsx", 'r') as zip_ref:
    zip_ref.extractall(f""+hyper+"/Rules")
```

I tried the above code, which is working only one time.
how can I keep opening the file?

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text (formatted as code) in the question.

Comment: What do you mean with "working only one time"? Why do you want to execute it more often?